# WinMergeで変更の無い部分も表示させる方法

Tags: untagged

WinMergeで差分を見ながら作業していました。
表示方法はいじらず、デフォルト設定のままでしたが、何かの拍子に、差分の部分のみ表示されるようになってしまいました。
背景が全て黄色い状況です。

差分のみでなく、ファイルの中身を表示できるようにしたいのですが、どうやって戻せばいいでしょうか？

TortoiseGit
WinMerge

追記：
上記の過程で空白も表示されなくなってしまいました。
表示→空白を表示、を選択したのですが↩のような表記がでました。

デフォルトであった、色分けで空白の差分を表示させる方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diff コンテキスト](https://so-zou.jp/software/tech/tool/diff/winmerge/compare/file.htm#no3) の設定を確認してください。

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>のショートカットでトグルするので、保存(Ctrl + S)と押し間違えてしまうケースがあります。